# How to implement parallax background on a grouped GridView inside Semantic Zoom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, parallax

I'm trying to implement a nice-looking horizontally scrolled gridview inside my app. I have already implemented it using the [Q42.WinRT library](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT) like this:

```
    <Canvas>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="768">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform
                   TranslateX="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset, Converter={StaticResource ParallaxConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Image Source="/Assets/3.jpg" Width="1366" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Assets/1.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Assets/2.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
    <ScrollViewer
       x:Name="MyScrollViewer"
       HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Height="768">
    <GridView>
      //...my gridview goes here
    </GridView> </ScrollViewer>
```

Everything works fine, however in my app I need to use semantic zoom, and I found that semantic zoom does NOT WORK properly when put inside a ScrollViewer.

Generally all the solutions for parallactic backgrounds that I found on the internet implement some kind of functionality over a scrollviewer, which is unfortunate for me as I cannot use it.

Can anybody think of another way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Be sure and check performance on ARM devices. This is a common performance killer. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Jerry. I have a Surface sitting right next to me and so far I have yet to see it underperform!

Comment: Yeah. Surface is pretty decent.

Comment: Any device can underperform when you push it hard. :) Try putting a few layers of semi-transparent images in your UI and compare the performance on a Surface and on an Intel PC. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally putting GridViews inside a ScrollViewer is not a great idea since they already have ScrollViewers inside of them...

You should put your 2 GridViews inside a SemanticZoom.

Perhaps you could edit the template for your GridView and put a parallax background in there - perhaps as a Canvas with some content that responds to the ViewChanged events on the GridView.

EDIT*

You inspired me to try to write a ParallaxBackgroundBehavior for the Toolkit. :)

You can see an early version [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f8ef5ce66b68#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Behaviors/ParallaxBackgroundBehavior.cs). There is also a [sample included](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f8ef5ce66b68#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Behaviors/ParallaxBackgroundBehaviorTestPage.xaml).

Comment: Thanks Filip, I will try it out now!